# find() using Functional Programming

Tags: swift, generics, functional-programming

I'd like to create a generic find() typically used in functional programming. In functional programming you don't work with array indices and for loops. You filter. The way it works is that if you have a list of say

```
["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
```

and you want to find banana then you assign the array indices to the list elements by creating tuples

```
[(1, "apple"), (2, "banana"), (3, "cherry")]
```

Now you can filter down to "banana" and return the index value.

I was trying to create a generic function for this but I get an error. What's wrong with this syntax?

```
func findInGenericIndexedList<T>(indexedList: [(index: Int, value: T)], element: (index: Int, value: T)) -> Int? {        
    let found = indexedList.filter {   // ERROR: Cannot invoke 'filter' with an argument list of type '((_) -> _)'

        element.value === $0.value
    }

    if let definiteFound = found.first {
        return definiteFound.index
    }
    return nil
}
```

**UPDATE 1**: I would like to use the above solution as opposed to using find() (will be deprecated) or in Swift 2.0 indexOf() because I'm trying to follow the Functional Programming paradigm, relying on general functions and not class methods.

Comment: 1) In `element === $0.value` you compare a tuple of type `(Int, T)` with a value of type `T`. 2) `===`, the "identical-to" operator, is defined only for instances of *classes*. 3) Are you aware that Swift already has a `find` function? (In Swift 2 it is called `indexOf`.)

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I updated my question why find() indexOf() are not my preferred solutions. I updated the code based on your point 1. That makes sense, however it still doesn't work. If the '===' identity operator doesn't work in such cases, how would you write a generic function like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimum change required to make this work would be to make T conform to Equatable and use the == operator.

```
func findInGenericIndexedList<T:Equatable>(indexedList: [(index: Int, value: T)], element: (index: Int, value: T)) -> Int? {
    let found = indexedList.filter {
        element.value == $0.value
    }

    if let definiteFound = found.first {
        return definiteFound.index
    }
    return nil
}
```

It doesn't really make sense to use === here because are usually going to be applying this to value types (especially if you are following functional paradigms) for which this is never true.

Beyond this I spent some time thinking about the problem and here is what I would do:

```
extension Array where Element : Equatable {
    func find(element:Array.Generator.Element) -> Int? {
        let indexedList = lazy(self.enumerate())
        let found = indexedList.filter {
            element == $1
        }

        let definiteFound = found.prefix(1)
        return definiteFound.generate().next()?.index
    }
}
```

Protocol extension on Array because it makes the syntax neater, lazy sequence to avoid checking every element, 0 indexed.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborative answer. I would still prefer to use the identity operator '===', because in my array I may have multiple items of the same value. However, I want to delete the exact item that I passed to the function. Is it impossible to do this? (I really like your extension. It might be less functional programming and a bit more OO, though. FP works more with higher order functions. Everything is passed.)

Comment: How do you define "the exact item"? Is is an item with the same index and the same content? I.e., where the (Int, String) tuple will be the same? Or do you anticipate having multiple tuples with exactly the same content?

Comment: @Roman Well obviously you wouldn't already know the index. Otherwise you could just return that.

Comment: @Tristan: In the example function that he wrote, he passes in an Element that is a tuple that contains the index and the value. I find the whole exercise a little weird, because I'm not sure why he's creating (index, value) tuples for items in an array, but that's what he's got. An array of (index, value) tuples, and he's searching for the tuple that matches (index, value). So he appears to think he's going to know the index before he searches for it. I know. I don't get it either. My comment was intended to get him to clarify a little...

Comment: @Tristan, I'm not looking for the tuple. I'm looking for the element (the second variable in the tuple) and return the corresponding index. This is how you'd find the index in Functional Programming (please see beginning of the post.) The point is that I know the element that I'm working with -- I have a reference to it. Now, I'd like to have it's index in the array. So, don't want to compare values because (a) I may have duplicates and (b) because element (2nd variable in the tuple) may actually be a complex structure with many complex properties.  How can I do this in a generic func?

Comment: @Daniel This could be done with classes by making T conform to AnyObject instead of Equatable but it wouldn't be very functional to restrict the function to objects. If you have complex structs you should just make them out of smaller structs each of which are equatable, then you can compare each of the inner structs for your comparison. This means at any level the check is relatively simple.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of thoughts.

> I would still prefer to use the identity operator '===', because in my array I may have multiple items of the same value.

The identity operator `===` only works for reference types, like classes. It will never work for value types, like `String`s or `Int`s, or `struct`s, etc. You might take a look at the difference between value types and reference types, especially if you are interested in functional programming, which eschews reference types almost completely. When you are working with value types, there is only equality (`==`) - there is no identity. Two instances of the `String` "`bananas`" will never refer to the same identical object. They will always refer to two different `String`s, though their *values* might be *equal*.

> I want to delete the exact item that I passed to the function. Is it impossible to do this?

If you are working with value types, like `String`s, then yes, it is impossible. There is no such thing as two different `String`s that are the exact same item. Two `String`s are always are always different objects, for the reasons stated above.

Note that if you work only with classes, and not value types, then you could use the `===` operator, but this would defeat much of what you are trying to do.

What this boils down to is that if you have an array of `(index, value)` tuples that looks like this:

```
[(0, "bananas"), (1, "apples"), (2, "oranges"), (3, "bananas")]
```

And you write a function that looks for tuples where the value is `"bananas"`, you have a couple of choices. You can filter it and look for the *first* tuple in the array that has the value `"bananas"` and return the index of that tuple. In the above case it would return `0`. Or, you could return *all* of the indexes in the form of an array, like this: `[0, 3]`. Or I suppose you could return some other arbitrary subset of the results, like the *last* index, or the *first-and-last* indexes, etc., but those all seem a little silly. The Swift standard library opts for returning the index of the first item that matches the search criteria for precisely this reason. None of the other options make a whole lot of sense.

But putting it back into the context of your question, none of the tuples that you find with the value of `"bananas"` are going to be the exact (identical) instance of `"bananas"` that you passed in to your search function. No two value types are ever identical. They may be equal, but they are never identical.

One more note - mainly for clarification of what you are even trying to do. In your first attempt at writing this function, you appear to already know the index of the item you are searching for. You pass it in to the function as a parameter, right here:

```
                                                                     // ----------vvvvv
func findInGenericIndexedList<T>(indexedList: [(index: Int, value: T)], element: (index: Int, value: T)) -> Int?
```

Just out of curiosity, is this a typo? Or do you actually know the index of the tuple that you are searching for? Because if you already know what it is, well... you don't need to search for it :)

Comment: Yes, it is a typo. :) I should only pass the element. Thanks again for the detailed reply. I'm surprised that you can't look for the identical reference. Primitive types, Strings, complex types, they all have references to them. Even when immutable. I accept that you can't do this but I still don't understand why. Why can't I check if an object / primitive type / any type has the same reference as the one "I'm holding in my hand" (i.e., passed as a parameter)?

Comment: It is a language feature of Swift. Value types are safer, because changing one instance doesn't change every other instance that is "referred to". Both value types and reference types are valuable in their own way.

Comment: That makes sense. Agreed.